# What are all the various "tasks" involved in the activities associated with "Continuous Integration"?

Tags: eclipse, maven, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, rtc

Say using Maven with Eclipse and Rational Team Concert (for SC).

New here so thanks for your help! I'm trying to build a little process model to help me visualize how this all works, so if you knew of a link to something like a swim lane diagram which shows how CI works with these or similar tools, that'd be even better.

Answer (score 1):

RTC and maven are linked through BuildForge: see "[Build and Process Automation](https://jazz.net/projects/rational-team-concert/integrations/build-mgmt/)".

In this Wiki article "[A Jazz-based Maven build](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/MavenBuild)" (free registration required to access that article), you can see how you can setup a simple Jazz-based build for an existing Maven project.

From there, you can start define your BuildForge jobs able to detect any change in the history, and trigger a Maven build.